# Toshiba Satellite error 10053A0000 when re installing windows xp home on an existing windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, reinstall

I had installed windows 7 for testing. Now i want to re-install windows xp home original. I am using the toshiba installation(recovery) disk. The installation process asked a few questions. I selected the option to retain other partitions and to delete only c drive. In the next step i got this error.

http://web1.toshiba.ca/support//techsupport/tsbs/all/-tsb001404.htm
[image]

So, what should i do to retain my files in d drive and only allow the installation to delete c drive?

Comment: From the link you posted, " To correct this issue, it is necessary to delete all partitions."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that is not possible with the recovery disk.  You could remove the drive and connect it to a working system either directly or in an external enclosure and copy the data from the D Partition.  Once the recovery is complete, you can copy the data back to the laptop as needed .